# Only allow Lambda functions to call API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I have serverless project currently running on api-gateway pointing to 2 aws lambda functions. Each lambda function can handle their route too. For example

```
/service/1/public/{proxy+} point to lambda function 1
/service/2/public/{proxy+} point to lambda function 2
```

Now the problem is I want to add apis like this

```
/service/1/internal/{proxy+} point to lambda function 1
```

Those internal apis should only called by code inside lambda function 1 or 2 (via httpclient). Can I setup a private path like this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, private endpoints for api gateway was released on June 2018. Here is the summary of steps you need to perform:

**Setting up a private endpoint**

Getting up and running with your private API Gateway endpoint requires just a few things:

- A virtual private cloud (VPC) configured with at least one subnet and DNS resolution enabled.
- A VPC endpoint with the following configuration:

  - Service name = “com.amazonaws.{region}.execute-api”
  - Enable Private DNS Name = enabled
  - A security group set to allow TCP Port 443 inbound from either an IP range in your VPC or another security group in your VPC
- An API Gateway managed API with the following configuration:

  - Endpoint Type = “Private”
  - An API Gateway resource policy that allows access to your API from the VPC endpoint

For more details see: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/